# SQL: Computing Max value based on Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, max

I have a table that has the following properties

1. UserName: identifier
2. Sequence: this is an ordered list to indicate a sequence of events
3. Aggregated: this is also sequential.  For instance if a response was taken for a particular event, then a value is present (1 indicating the first action, 2 indicating the second action, ...,  0 indicates no action was taken for that event).

I need to add another column which replaces the 0 with max value for same user **up to that point**.  See Second table for example. For instance, even though there was no action taken on event 3, there had been 2 actions up to that point, thus 2 should be the value associated with the row.

Running SQL Server 2008 R2

```
| Username  | Seq | Agg|
------------------------
| Username1 |  1  | 1  |
| Username1 |  2  | 2  |
| Username1 |  3  | 0  |
| Username1 |  4  | 0  | 
| Username1 |  5  | 3  |



| Username  | Seq | Agg| Act|
-----------------------------
| Username1 |  1  | 1  | 1  |
| Username1 |  2  | 2  | 2  |
| Username1 |  3  | 0  | 2  |
| Username1 |  4  | 0  | 2  |
| Username1 |  5  | 3  | 3  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most dialects of SQL support ANSI standard window functions.  You haven't mentioned which database, so let's assume that you are using one:

```
select a.*,
       max(agg) over (partition by username order by seq) as act
from atable a;
```

If your database doesn't support window functions (or the cumulative max), you can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
       (select max(a2.agg)
        from atable a2
        where a2.id <= a.id
       ) as act
from atable a;
```

Comment: The second method worked for me; the first method did not seem to have the logic that restricts the max value to only those records with a seq value less than the current record's value (it returned the max value when among all records matching the user)

Comment: @user2036380 . . . SQL Server 2008 doesn't support cumulative max.